# Outgoing emails are not signing with DKIM

Tags: email, smtp, postfix, dkim

I have set up Postfix and OpenDKIM and I am trying to get outgoing emails signed by DKIM so that providers won't mark it as spam.

However, even if I believe I set up the signing properly, none of the outgoing emails are signed.

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/[My domain]/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/[My domain]/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers=high

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
postscreen_greet_action=enforce
smtpd_sender_restrictions=
   reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
   permit_sasl_authenticated
   reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
   reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
   reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
myhostname = [My domain]
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, [My domain], localhost.[My domain], localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128  [my public IPv6] [My Public IPv4]
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
disable_vrfy_command=yes
fast_flush_domains=
smtpd_etrn_restrictions=reject
inet_interfaces = all
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action=reject
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

"/etc/opendkim.conf"

```
# This is a basic configuration for signing and verifying. It can easily be
# adapted to suit a basic installation. See opendkim.conf(5) and
# /usr/share/doc/opendkim/examples/opendkim.conf.sample for complete
# documentation of available configuration parameters.

Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           yes
#LogWhy                 no

# Common signing and verification parameters. In Debian, the "From" header is
# oversigned, because it is often the identity key used by reputation systems
# and thus somewhat security sensitive.
Canonicalization        simple/simple
Mode                    sv
SubDomains              yes
OversignHeaders         From

# Signing domain, selector, and key (required). For example, perform signing
# for domain "example.com" with selector "2020" (2020._domainkey.example.com),
# using the private key stored in /etc/dkimkeys/example.private. More granular
# setup options can be found in /usr/share/doc/opendkim/README.opendkim.
Domain          [REDACTED]
Selector        s1
KeyFile         /etc/opendkim/keys/[My domain]/[My private key]

# In Debian, opendkim runs as user "opendkim". A umask of 007 is required when
# using a local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-privileged
# user (for example, Postfix). You may need to add user "postfix" to group
# "opendkim" in that case.
UserID                  opendkim
UMask                   007
                                                 
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
AutoRestart         yes
AutoRestartRate     10/1M
Background          yes
DNSTimeout          30
SignatureAlgorithm  rsa-sha256
KeyTable           refile:/etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table

# Hosts to ignore when verifying signatures
ExternalIgnoreList  /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts

# A set of internal hosts whose mail should be signed
InternalHosts       /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen

smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
policyd-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       0    spawn user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

How am I supposed to resolve this? Outlook keeps marking my email as spam and my IP is not eligible for mitigation, and GMX/Yandex block me straight out because of this.

Please help me resolve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried to follow all steps involved: 1 - configure DKIM 2 -generate signature 3 - update DNS 4 - restart opendkim and postfix services 5 - test using an outside tool?

Comment: Yes I did exactly as the steps you said

Comment: I will wait until DNS records propagate and get you back tomorrow

Comment: In /etc/postfix/main.cf try changing: milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2

in /etc/default/opendkim if you haven't done so, try modifying the default socket to: SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost"

Comment: FYI, in case you have access to CPanel on your website, there's a module called Email Deliverability that can help you to configure DKIM and other values with a couple of clicks

Comment: Please also provide logs covering the respective messages not signed with DKIM. Otherwise it is difficult to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I have changed the main.cf and the socke is already "inet:8891@localhost" and the logs show nothing......

Comment: Check `grep dkim /var/log/mail.log` and `grep dkim /var/log/syslog`. Either `postfix` or `opendkim` should be complaining somewhere. Note that the messages should be signed regardless of and DNS record configuration, so first get signatures into headers, then figure out if there are DNS related problems.

Comment: Now the outgoing mail log doesn't even log to syslog and nothing about DKIM but the messages are still not signed

Comment: Now I use `sendmail` instead of `swaks` and get at least signing working but unfortunately on the recipient side it shows "key not found in DNS"

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. `swaks` simply doesn't support DKIM, and "key not found in DNS" is because I put the selector in the `key.table` file wrong!